# How do I choose what traditional character variants I want on Windows 10?

Tags: traditional-characters, input-methods

I write Chinese with traditional characters as they are used in Taiwan, using Microsoft Pinyin IME on Windows 10. This mostly works fine, but sometimes Windows seems dead set on giving me a variant of a character that I don't want.

Examples: I'm trying to type 週 but I get 周, I want 掛 but get 挂, I want 裡 and get 裏. In the first two cases I can get to the desired character by scrolling several pages in the IME candidates (though that's obviously annoying), in the last case I couldn't get it at all.

My keyboard is set to “Chinese (simplified, China)” but in the IME options I selected traditional characters. I didn't set it directly to “Chinese (traditional, Taiwan)”, because I couldn't figure out how to use Pinyin that way.

Any advice on what I might do different? Is there some setting to teach Windows what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Rojetto wrote:
> I'm trying to type 週 but I get 周, I want 掛 but get 挂, I want 裡 and get 裏.

The reason is connected to the use of the "Chinese (Simplified, China)" IME.

My first suggestion is to 1) add "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)" and 2) set "HanYu Pinyin" the following way:

**1) Add "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)"**

Settings -->
System -->
Time & Language -->
Language -->
Add a language -->
"Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)" -->
Next -->
Install

Don't close the "Language" page.

**2) Set "HanYu Pinyin"**

Once added "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)", click on it and then:

Options -->
Microsoft Bopomofo -->
Options -->
Key assignment

Under "Select your preferred keyboard layout" select "HanYu Pinyin".

---

> @Rojetto wrote:
> How do I choose what traditional character variants I want on Windows 10?

**General rule**

No matter what IME you use, instead of confirming the input after each single character, it is better to write complete words or phrases and, while the characters are still underlined, with the left arrow move back and modify the wrong characters.

P.s.: 裡 is still there even in the "Chinese (Simplified, China)" with the traditional "Character set". It's just near the end of the long list of "li".

Comment: Thank you, that certainly answers the main question. Using the actual Taiwanese IME I get the character variants I'm used to.

I'll have to relearn a little muscle memory for navigating the candidate window though. If I just want to type one character (say 眾), with the Bopomofo (Pinyin) IME I have to type z h o n g, then Space to get a character, then Down to open the candidates, then I can type the number of the one I want. With the simplified Pinyin IME, I just had to type z h o n g, then immediately type the candidate number. Maybe you could tell me whether I'm missing something again?

Comment: @Rojetto Yes, I know, there are pros and cons. One of the feature I like is that you can add the tone (a number from 1 to 5) after the syllable. Another feature I like is the Hand Writing.